# $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^p}{n!} \in \: e\mathbb{N}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $p \in \mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}.$ Show that

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{n^p}{n!} \in \: e\mathbb{N}$$

I have already shown the convergence using Stirling's formula.

Comment: The sum is $e$ times the $p$'th Bell number, see [OEIS sequence A000110](https://oeis.org/A000110)

Comment: Hint: Let $f(x)=e^{e^x}-1=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n!}e^{nx}$. Now differentiate $f$ $p$ times (and put $x=0$ afterwards).

Comment: @JackLeGrüß, $p$-th derivative of $f(x)$ is complicated, you have to prove $f^{(p)}(x) = P_p(e^x)f(x)$ with $P_p\in\mathbb{Z}[X]$ by induction. In the end it is the same to consider $f_p(x) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n^p}{n!}x^n$

Comment: @ne3886: You don’t really need to calculate it (unless you want the precise value). You only need to observe that the $p$th derivative of $f$ is a sum of natural number multiples of $e^{kx}e^{e^x}$ (for $1\le k\le p$) and at $x=0$, you obtain the conclusion desired by the OP.

Comment: @JackLeGrüß, how do you calculate $p$th derivative without using induction?

Comment: @ne3886: It (the observation) surely is by induction (but you need not compute the natural number multiples of $e^{kx}e^{e^x}$, just the (quick evaluation/observation) that the derivative of the $e^{kx}e^{e^x}$ is $e^{(k+1)x}e^{e^x}+ke^{kx}e^{e^x}$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done in a totally elementary way. Write $(n)_k = n(n-1) \dots (n-(k-1)) = \frac{n!}{(n-k)!}$ for the [falling factorial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Falling_and_rising_factorials). First, observe that

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n)_k}{n!} = \sum_{n=k}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n-k)!} = e.$$

Second, prove by induction (or otherwise, e.g. using finite differences) that there exist integers $\left\{ k \atop i \right\}$ such that

$$n^k = \sum_{i=0}^k \left\{ k \atop i \right\} (n)_i.$$

Then

$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{n!} = e \sum_{i=0}^k \left\{ k \atop i \right\}.$$

Incidentally, $\left\{ k \atop i \right\}$ are the [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind), but you don't need this to prove the desired result. This sum can be interpreted as ($e$ times) the $k^{th}$ moment of the [Poisson distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_distribution) with $\lambda = 1$, and the Stirling number formula shows that it is equal to ($e$ times) the [Bell number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell_number) $B_k$; this result is called [Dobinski's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dobinski%27s_formula).

---

Okay, an even easier argument is available: we can do it directly by strong induction. Write

$$S_k = \frac{1}{e} \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{n!}.$$

We have $S_0 = 1$ and in general

$$\begin{align} S_{k+1} &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{n^{k+1}}{n!} \\
 &= \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{n^k}{(n-1)!} \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(n+1)^k}{n!} \\
 &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n!} \left( \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i} n^i \right) \\
 &= \sum_{i=0}^k {k \choose i} S_i \end{align}.$$

This is a recurrence satisfied by the Bell numbers, but you don't need this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following argument. Define
$$f(x):=e^{e^x}-1=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{1}{n!}e^{nx}\,.$$
Observe that the $p$th derivative of the series is
$$f^p(x)=\sum_{n\ge 1}\frac{n^p}{n!}e^{nx}\,,$$
hence your desired sum is simply $f^p(0)$.  To see that is satisfies your conclusion, we use the explicit expression for $f$ and consider the base case $f’(x)=e^xe^{e^x}$ and suppose $f^k(x)=\sum_{j=1}^ka_je^{jx}e^{e^x}$ for some natural numbers $a_j$; then we have
$$f^{k+1}(x)=\sum_{j=1}^ka_j\frac{d}{dx}e^{jx}e^{e^x}$$
$$=\sum_{j=1}^ka_j\left(e^{(j+1)x}e^{e^x}+j e^{jx}e^{e^x}\right)$$
$$=\sum_{j=1}^{k+1}(a_{j-1}+a_jj)e^{jx}e^{e^x}\,,$$
where $a_0:=0$. We quickly conclude that $f^p(x)$ is a sum over natural number multiples of $e^{kx}e^{e^x}$ for all $1\le k\le p$, and hence $f^p(0)\in e\mathbb{N}$, as desired.